# How to fix "unresolved external error" in Microsoft Visual Studio Community when using template functions?

Tags: c++, templates, unresolved-external

I think I have managed to fix my errors, but my program works properly on only some compilers, but it doesn't work on other ones, like Microsoft Visual Studio, and I have no idea how to fix it.

It raises such an error:

> unresolved external symbol main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void) (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)"

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define E '\n'
#define ll long long

template<typename T>
class BinarySearch
{
public:
    BinarySearch(T target, T elements[])
        :elements(elements), target(target)
    { }

    bool solve(int start_index, int end_index)
    {
        int mid_index = (start_index + end_index) / 2;

        if (start_index >= end_index)
        {
            if (elements[start_index] == target)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (elements[mid_index] == target)
                return true;
            else if (elements[mid_index] < target)
                return solve(mid_index + 1, end_index);
            else
                return solve(start_index, mid_index - 1);
        }
    }

private:
    T* elements;
    T target;
};

template<typename T>
int main()
{
    int elements[] = { 1,2,3,47,111,121,681,990 };

    int target = 0;

    BinarySearch solution(target, elements);

    cout << solution.solve(0, 7);

    return 0;
}
```

I desperately need to fix these compile errors.

Comment: Main cannot be templated, what is `template<typename T>` doing there?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but macros like `E` and `ll` doesn't make your code better in any way. It's actually the opposite.

Comment: `template<typename T> int main()` That won't fly. `main` can't be a template. Drop `template<typename T>` part.

Comment: Why did you make `main` a template? What problem was that supposed to solve?